# "Iterating"? For MA and AR processes

Tags: time-series, stationarity

I am not sure what is being done here, but I keep seeing statements like

Given $X_t - \phi X_{t-1} = Z_t$ $...(1)$

then
$$X_t = -\phi^{-1}Z_{t+1} + \phi^{-1}X_{t+1}$$
$$ = ... $$
$$= -\phi^{-1}Z_{t+1} - ... - -\phi^{-k-1}Z_{t+k+1}+\phi^{-1-k}X_{t+k+1}$$

What is going on here? What is the purpose of this?

If it helps, the concluding argument is that 
$X_t = - \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \phi^{-j}Z_{t+j}$ is the unique stationary solution of $(1)$